# Output is not shown when trying to run C program

Tags: c

When I try to run this program, my terminal doesn't display anything.

Here is the program:

```
/* Print a message on the screen*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

**--EDIT--**

My antivirus was blocking the execution of the program.

Comment: Try adding a newline to flush the output. `printf("Hello World.\n");` Anyway, are you running the program *from the terminal* command line? If not, maybe the terminal window opens and closes so fast you don't even see it. If so you can also add `getchar();` after the `printf` statement.

Comment: How did you compile and run your code? Some compiler settings may disable standard input/output.

Comment: Is that the whole program? Did you get any errors or warnings when you compiled? What did you type in to run it? What OS are you using?

Comment: Did you save the file after typing in the code?

Comment: What environment are you on? Are you using any IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Add a newline to the end of your string (or use `puts`):

```
/* Print out a message on the screen*/

#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Usually compilers will optimize this `printf` call to `puts("Hello, World.")`.

It is also recommended to declare `main` as an `int` (use `int main() ...`).

Comment: The output should be automatically flushed when the program exits regardless.

Comment: Should be... But who knows? I could edit my answer to add `fflush(stdout)` if it helps...

Comment: C11 §7.21.3 States *5 The file may be subsequently reopened, by the same or another program execution, and its contents reclaimed or modified (if it can be repositioned at its start). If the main function returns to its original caller, or if the exit function is called, all open files are closed (**hence all output streams are flushed**) before program termination. Other paths to program termination, such as calling the abort function, need not close all files properly.* (My bolding).

Comment: So this guy's C compiler/implementation are either not standards-compliant or there's something else going on. I know that Windows only has C90 support. That may be it.

Comment: My bet is that "there's something else going on" that hasn't been revealed by the OP.

Comment: Yeah. That happens a lot. See the OP's updated question.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function in C you need to specify the return type.
So your main function has to be declared as `int main()` (because it returns an integer)

Comment: This shouldn't matter about output. I believe that the terminal prompt is overwriting the OP's output because the OP didn't use a newline in the string passed to `printf`.

Comment: Sorry I thought that wasn't accepted as a main function by the compiler and thus didn't compile, my bad